# Is it necessary to add [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)] above every class in a Xamarin Forms App?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I thought I had read before that this was only needed for the App class but now when I go to the sample tabbed application that is part of the Xamarin Form official templates I see it added above every class.

Can someone please confirm.  Just the one class or every class when it is added?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both are acceptable.

If you want to enable compiled XAML through out your application just set
[assembly: XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
just above your namespace in App.cs file as below:

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace App
{
   ....

}
```

If you want to enable per file then set it as below at class level.

```
[XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public class TestPage : ContentPage
{
    ....
}
```

Read out more on this at:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/optimizing-xamarin-forms-apps-for-maximum-performance/

Comment: I commented out all these from all the classes, now can compile. But what is the impact for removing all these lines?

Answer (score 5):

No, you can add an assembly level attribute just once for it to include all your XAML files:

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
```

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
...
[assembly: XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace SomeApp
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought, so I'm wondering why the person who created the official Xamarin Tabbed page template has added it everywhere.  hmm

Comment: In that Xamarin sample, it's added above every class but you added it above the namespace. What about if there are multiple namespaces?

Comment: It is an assembly level (`[assembly: XamlCompilation...`) attribute so it is only needed once per CIL assembly. If you have XAML pages in different projects/assemblies you will need to add it once to each one of those projects.

Comment: Some older XAML code might not be compatible with the XAMLC so it is not defaulted to an `on` state and thus doing it at a page/class level might make sense for generic code being used across a wide range of user's projects

Answer (score 2):

The essence is to improve speed and overall performace, so it's important to use any of the forms of XamlCompilation as explained by SushiHangover.

However to do improve the speed more, add this code to MainActivity.cs in the Android project, just before the Xamarin Forms initialization.

```
 Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("FastRenderers_Experimental");
```

Comment: Fast renderers can improve performance on Android, but they have nothing to do with the question, which is specifically about XAML compilation.

Comment: You don't know how to understand the true intents of questions. Poor verbal reasoning?? The question shows he has a very basic or un-researched understanding of Xaml Compilations which ultimately improves over all performance. I thought of him as someone who is rooting for performance, and so I gave him further ideas on how to improve the performance. I'm sure this is done in any community.

Comment: Read the title of the question again: 
"Is it necessary to add [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)] above every class in a Xamarin Forms App?"
Your answer simply does not address the question. You're not the first person to be flagged for inaccurate answers. Don't take it personally. 
Furthermore, fast renderers are experimental and commonly break with newer releases of Xamarin.Android. I worked at Xamarin Inc for two years.

Comment: Any insight as to why Xamarin inc did build a proper form designer?